# Using Google Search "Did you mean?" for Books API

Tags: google-search-api, google-books

I'm currently building a book search application using the Google Books API. I am sending the search term to Google Books API via a query parameter string in URL.

Let's say I am searching for the book The Game of Chess by Harry Golombek.

If I submit to the API: "the game of chess h goiombek" with the name spelled wrong, the search results will not include the book that I am after.

However if I go to book search on Google and use the same search term, it will suggest "Did you mean: the game of chess h **golombek**". Only after clicking this will the correct book appear.

So how can I use Google's search engine to autocorrect my search terms? There are many resources on how to build you own did-you-mean functionality, however I want to use Google's.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess tihs is what you are looking for-

[Autocomplete](https://simplestepscode.com/autocomplete-data-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for the post. Can this be done from a phone app?

Comment: Have a look at this- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog